# Check if After a Specific Time or Same Day

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datetime, timespan

Our VB .Net code currently does a check to determine if a request is being submitted for the same day (e.g. I'm submitting a request today *for* today). It does this by looking at the time zone associated with the zip code of the request.

This works well, but I want to modify the logic so that the check starts/triggers at 10pm the night before. The current code will only trigger starting at midnight of the same day. In other words, the process is triggered not just for same day, but also if the time that the request is submitted is 10pm or later the day before.

```
If oSearch.RequestDate.Date = 
Provider.GetLocalTimeByZipCode(oSearch.ZipCode, 
Now).Date Then
<do computer stuff>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you need to handle DLS. For these type of logic, I sometime just subtract or add 2 hour to the date I want to check.

If not, you'll need to get the range of dates. Something like:

```
Dim curDate = Provider.GetLocalTimeByZipCode(oSearch.ZipCode, 
Now).Date
Dim startDate = curDate.Day.AddHours(-2)
Dim endDate = curDate.Day.AddHours(10)

If oSearch.RequestDate.Date >= startDate AndAlso oSearch.RequestDate.Date <= endDate Then
```